# Python Plotly-Dash: Problem when converting uploaded image in base64 to string or PIL.Image

Tags: python, base64, python-imaging-library, plotly-dash

I am facing a huge problem when I'm uploading an image (.jpg or .png) via the dcc.upload component: I have to feed the image into a function that accepts either a string or PIL.Image object. In my opinion it would be better to convert it to a PIL.Image (?). So I have to convert the base64 encoded image to a PIL.Image object but I cannot get this to work. I am able to display the uploaded image in dash though. Please help!

I tried the following: (uploaded image is called `upload`, function for further use called `function`)

- Using `upload` object itself: `OSError: [Errno 63] File name too long: 'data:image/png;base64,iVB...`
- `function(base64.b64decode(upload, 'rb'))`: `assert isinstance(image, str) or isinstance(image, Image.Image)`
- `function(Image.open(base64.b64decode(upload, 'rb')))`: `ValueError: embedded null byte`
- `function(Image.open(BytesIO(base64.b64decode(upload, 'rb'))))`: `OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x146225d10>`
- Using `upload = base64.b64decode(upload + '===')` didn't help
- Using `ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True` didn't help

But the image file can't be corrupted as I can clearly display it in the browser?
And getting a string (or path) out of it is also not a good idea I think as the image will be uploaded from the user?

Thanks!